# Soft question: How to pronounce "Clairaut"

Tags: multivariable-calculus, soft-question, terminology

I'm preparing for a presentation tomorrow and I will refer to clairaut's theorem in multivariable calculus (mixed partials are equal)

Can French speakers chime in as to how to correctly pronounce clairaut (for an english speaker). Is it pronounced "clear-roo" or..

Thanks!

Comment: claire-oh, without making the oh long

Comment: You could always call it Schwarz's theorem or Young's theorem or the equality of mixed partials...

Comment: When in doubt, I like to listen to how Google says it: https://translate.google.com/#en/fr/clairaut

Comment: in IPA: /klɛʁo/

Comment: nothing wrong with asking your audience how to pronounce an unfamiliar name

Comment: It’s a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-SHQ1FMyqIo  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jUfCpkIji0I